# Neo4j - Specify a Unidirectional Relationship Type

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm working with neo4j, calling it from Java. 
I noticed that when using Dijkstras algorithm, it picks every relationship as to be bidirectional. I wanted to know how to create relationships that are unidirectional.

So far, what I'm doing is:

```
Relationship relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, link);
```

Is it possible to include a direction in the relationship?

Comment: The problem is not the relationship itself. Neo4j relationships ARE unidirectional. The problem is your query. If you could add your query here, I may be able to help you.

Comment: Therefore, if I want them to be in a bidirectional relationship, I have to add secondNode.createRelationshipTo(firstNode, link) ? The code is:  ` PathFinder<WeightedPath> dijkstra = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(
            PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections(), "LENGTH" );
        WeightedPath path = dijkstra.findSinglePath( nodeA, nodeB ); `

Comment: Solved, creating double relationships when needed and using PathExpanders.forDirection(Direction.OUTGOING)